# mongoose is not working with php-cgi

Tags: php, http, mongoose-web-server

I tried to use *mongoose* embedded webserver with *php-cgi*, but the files is keeping to show the source code:

```
<?php echo "1"; ?>
```

I am using this command with *mongoose*:

```
./mongoose -C php -I /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Tried `mg_set_option (context, "cgi_interp", "/usr/bin/php-cgi");`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++ or C. I'm removing those tags. Please don't tag things unnecessarily in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you should modify the file '/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini' or '/etc/php.ini/',set the 'doc_root' same to the 'document_root'.It will be ok！

Answer (score 0):

It seems `mongoose` is working fine, but `php` is not.

Are you sure `php-cgi` is available on your system? Or maybe `php-cgi` is installed but the path you are using (`/usr/bin/php-cgi`) is not right.

Try running on your terminal `which php-cgi` and check the response. If you get no response it means that you have to install it.
To install `php-cgi` on MacOS read this: http://wayneeaker.com/blog/2012/04/05/setting-php-cgi-mac-os-x, it worked for me.
On ubuntu it's easier: `sudo apt-get install php5-cgi`.